# Is it possible to not load an iframe in a hidden div, until the div is displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

Basically, a hidden div that's shown when a customer clicks on a link. That div displays a php formail that asks the customer questions about the product he/she is interested in.

Here's the code i found online that works great for me using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


$('.show_hide').showHide({           
    speed: 500,  // speed you want the toggle to happen 
    easing: '',  // the animation effect you want. Remove this line if you dont want an effect and if you haven't included jQuery UI
    changeText: 1, // if you dont want the button text to change, set this to 0
    showText: 'REQUEST A QUOTE',// the button text to show when a div is closed
    hideText: 'CLOSE' // the button text to show when a div is open

}); 


});

</script>
```

The css is just simple:

```
#slidingDiv, #slidingDiv_2{
height:300px;
background-color: #e2e2e2;
padding:20px;
margin-top:10px;
border-bottom:30px solid #000000;
display:none;
}
```

Here's the external java script:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).click(function () { 

         $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);    
         // this var stores which button you've clicked
         var toggleClick = $(this);
         // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
         var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
         // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
         $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
         // this only fires once the animation is completed
         if(options.changeText==1){
         $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
         }
          });

      return false;

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

Now it is my believe that in this code, the form would automatically load, even if not shown. I could be wrong, please correct me if so.

**Question**, how can i make sure this iframe inside the div would only load when the div is no longer hidden?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent loading the content of a hidden iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868252/prevent-loading-the-content-of-a-hidden-iframe)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Rather than loading the `iframe` with its `src` attribute, load it instead with a `data-src` attribute. For its value, provide the eventual location you'd use when the parent `div` becomes visible.

```
<div class="hidden_element">
    <iframe data-src="http://msdn.microsoft.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

When you show the parent `div`, issue a callback that takes the `iframe` attribute `data-src`, and sets its value to the `src` attribute of the `iframe`, causing it to load.

```
// Show our element, then call our callback
$(".hidden_element").show(function(){
    // Find the iframes within our newly-visible element
    $(this).find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
        // Set their src attribute to the value of data-src
        return $(this).data("src");
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bLUkk/