# SoundCloud iframe embed producing IndexSizeError

Tags: dom, iframe, ssl, https, soundcloud

I am embedding a standard iframe into a non-ssl web page which displays a SoundCloud music player. The player loads fine, but I find errors in Safari developer tools saying the following:

> IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.

Additional related error showing up in Chrome browser:

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0

The errors reference https://w.soundcloud.com/player/assets/layouts/visual-single-sound-67f5bd61.js - line 963.  I have tried Firefox as well, but get the same errors in the console.  Here is a sample of my iframe code:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F12345678&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true&visual=true"></iframe>
```

Any ideas how I can get rid of these errors?  Could it have something to do with the javascript loading from an HTTPS reference under my HTTP parent page?

Comment: How exactly is this an issue with HTTPS?

Comment: Not absolutely sure it is, but my page runs HTTP, and this error is trying to load via HTTPS protocol from within the iframe. Could be unrelated, but worth noting.

Comment: I have modified the title to be more specific to the issue and not suggesting an HTTPS issue.

Comment: Well, if that error comes from their code, you should probably ask them to fix it.

Comment: Yes, hence this post. Quote from SoundCloud's developer website: "Our team is answering technical questions on Stack Overflow".

Comment: Hey Tim, I don't seem to be able to reproduce the problem in neither Chrome, Safari or Firefox :( 

Is there a particular web page I could check – maybe it has something to do with the way it is embedded?

Comment: You're right. I have been doing more thorough testing and think I may have found the problem. I'm using Bootstrap 3 for the website, and had to show/hide some content based on the device browser. The SoundCloud iframes were duplicated in that hidden section of code (for displaying less audio players than full screen). When I removed that hidden/duplicated section of code, the errors went away. I know there are several ways to end up at the same result in web programming, but I just threw this together for testing and didn't consider it may be the cause. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 3):

I just run into this problem as well. The error message is the key. That kind of exception is thrown when the element holding SC's `iframe` is hidden with `display: none`. When an element is hidden this way, it's not possible to retrieve its dimensions nor of any of its children, which is what SC's code is trying to do, it's trying to retrieve dimensions of a child element (canvas). To solve the problem, start by setting your element with `visibility: hidden` before initializing the widget. Once the widget initiated you can set it with `display: none` to suit your needs. This way, it's possible to retrieve an element's dimensions and the error will not occur.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and [this SO question pointed me in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868252/prevent-loading-the-content-of-a-hidden-iframe).

Namely, set your iframe's `src` to `data-src='..'` and the `src=''`. When you show the element containing the iframe, just swap the `data-src` to the `src` attr. This is nice because it will prevent the iframe from loading until its needed (useful if you have a lot of iframes, like multiple Soundcloud embeds), and you wont get the host of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JDillon's answer to set the data-src and then switch the src when ready to init the player. Like so:

**html**

```
<iframe id="sc-widget" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="" data-src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3333333%3Fsecret_token%3Dx-xxxx&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

**js** (es6)

```
let widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget')
widgetIframe.src = widgetIframe.dataset.src
let $embedPlayer = SC.Widget(widgetIframe)

/* example of using soundcloud embed player */
$embedPlayer.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, () => {
  $embedPlayer.getDuration((duration) => setDuration(duration))
})

$embedPlayer.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, () => {
  $embedPlayer.getPosition((position) => setPosition(position))
})

function setPosition(pos) { console.log(pos) }
function setDuration(dur) { console.log(dur) }
```

Then I also agree with adi's answer that you cannot use `display: none;` to hide the player if you are creating your own player to control the soundcloud embed player. In this case you need to hide it with the following styles:

**css**

```
iframe {
  max-width: 10rem;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I found it's best to avoid the embedded player, which is a slow process and creates a lot of overhead if you only utilize basic functions. It's actually really easy. I done it on my own [project](https://github.com/adi518/litecloud/tree/react).

Comment: Yes but the embedded player, as bad as it is doesn't get rate limited in the same way as when using the soundcloud api. I set up a simple soundcloud player myself, https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-soundcloud-player and I agree if you don't have large play numbers this is a good option.

Comment: Good point. There might be a workaround for this limitation. This issue came up on the [Soundnode](http://www.soundnodeapp.com/) project.