# Will iframe in input type hidden being load?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

as the title on top will iframe in input type hidden being load when page is loaded?

For ex:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<iframe width="810" height="415" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5th14OTyeqU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>" />
```

Comment: Why not try it and find out what happens?

Comment: I just wonder with that piece of iframe code in hidden value will it load or not.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? I can tell you the answer to your direct question, but I'd rather help you out a bit more than just saying "yes" or "no" in my answer.

Comment: I have a webpage that has a few youtube videos being loaded inside the slider. Hence it increased the amount of page loading time. I was trying my luck to reduce the loading time. Any suggestion based on this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't load.

You can't put html elements inside the value attribute of an input tag like that. Generally speaking (I won't say always, since html is sometimes very, very weird), html attributes cannot contain more html.

If you're looking to prevent the youtube elements actually loading on the screen as you mentioned in your comment, your best bet is to be found in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437091/is-it-possible-to-not-load-an-iframe-in-a-hidden-div-until-the-div-is-displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css style='display:none', and an id for your iframe, like this:

```
<iframe id="youtube" width="810" height="415" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5th14OTyeqU" style="display:none;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<input type="text"  id="name"/>
```

After that, you can use javascript code:

```
        $("#name").focus(function(){
        $("#youtube").show();
      });
```

So when you click on the input text field, the iframe should show up (this way you can test if it works).

UPDATE: I think you also need an API for loading that video there, it will not work without that. You can use this link to get more details: [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: Display none just doesn't fit my needs. As I know it will still being loaded :/

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you need exactly. You want it to show up on your page or just load without displaying?